# PHP: Import csv file(created by export .xls) to array

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have database in xls, so i needed to export it to .csv

Now, I have a problem with import csv file to an array.

I tried (test):

```
$csvfile = $_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'];  
$handle = fopen($csvfile,"r");

while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false)
{
    echo $fileop[0];    
}
```

Problem is that the program is tring to read every single cell in csv (even this empty), so result is 28083947389 readed cells.

I wanted see what seperator is created and i opened my csv file in notepad(ex.):

```
name;surname;email[CR][LF]
testname;testsurname;email@email[CR][LF]
```

My goal is to read the csv file and import it to mysql through an array.

Comment: it's not a csv if the separator is a semicolon. Are you sure you are exporting to csv? Also, when exporting to csv, it should only export the range of rows and columns that contain your data. Are the rest of your rows and columns truly empty in your xls file? Double check the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: @Brino - csv is commonly used for any files where data has a single character separator, regardless of that character.... it need not be a comma, but could be tab, pipe (`|`), semi-colon, etc.... which is why `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` allow you to specify the separator character

Comment: I've edited my question ( on the end of the line i have [CR][LF]

Comment: But your code is reading every row and every cell in the csv file; what do you expect to happen?

Comment: But my code is reading WHOLE spreadsheet

Comment: Of course it is; you start at the beginning of the file, and loop to the end of the file.... I repeat, what do you expect to happen? beginning to end = whole of file.... what do you want to happen? What do you want to read? If it's the first hundred records, perhaps, then put a record counter in your code and terminate the loop when you reach 100

Comment: well... I dont know how many columns will be there. But it shouldnt be like, "next column is empty so i read next row" or "after column is \r\n = read next row" ? Actually i want just read csv (or xlsx, whatever) and save it to array like [col_name] -> [row1], [col_name ]-> [row2] etc.